# Java JDBC Hibernate API Exception Error

Tags: java, hibernate

Will JDBCException class give field name or propertyName when persistent code throw Constraint Volation Exception???

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.

The Hibernate `JDBCException` class does not have any methods to return a property name.

The `ConstraintViolationException` class has a method to extract the constraint name, but nothing further.

There may be information about field names in the error messages, *but unless the the javadoc says so* you cannot rely on this.  And it doesn't.  If you were to write code to extract field names that might be in the exceptions, you are liable to find that your code is non-portable, and / or liable to break between Hibernate versions.